# Encrypting a file with GnuPG in shell script

Tags: command-line, shell-script, gnupg

I'm trying to encrypt a .tar.gz with a passphrase from a shell script. I've tried gpg2 --passphrase whatever -c  but then gnupg-agent pops up a dialog asking for a password.

Never used GnuPG before so i know nothing about it.

Comment: --batch (15 characters)

Comment: It's better not to pass passwords as arguments. Use `gpg --passphrase-file filename` instead.

Comment: --batch --passphrase did the job. Knew about passphrase-file but i gain nothing from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `--batch` flag. User `new123456` commented above.